# Letter count function javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a quick question

I am trying to make a function that takes a string input `"aacbdgtg"`
and have it output an array like so:

```
[["a", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 1], ["d", 1], ["g", 2], ["t", 1]]
```

So far I have written

```
var hist = function(string) {
  var result = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (result.length === 0) {
      result.push([string[i], 1]);
    }
    else {
      for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
        if (string[i] === result[j][0]) {
          result[j][1]++;
        }
      }
      result.push([string[i], 1]);
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

And i get a result of

```
[["a", 2], ["a", 1], ["c", 1], ["b", 1], ["d", 1], ["g", 2], ["t", 1], ["g", 1]]
```

Any help would be great thank you as I cam stuck and need help, I am not sure how to check if an array already has another array with the same letter

For example I don't know how to check if [["a", 2], ["a", 1]]
has already used the letter "a"

Comment: It would be much easier to make an Object with properties of the names of the letters and those properties have values of how many occurrences there are.

Comment: You're doing `result.push([string[i], 1]);` even when you found a pair with `string[i]` in the loop already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way is to create  an object first afterwards create the array structure using it. Also you can use **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method here.

```js
var hist = function(str) {
  var result = [],
    temp;

  // generate the object which holds string count
  temp = str.split('').reduce(function(a, b) {
    a[b] = a[b] + 1 || 1;
    return a;
  }, {});

  // generate the result using the object
  var result = Object.keys(temp).map(function(v) {
    return [v, temp[v]];
  });

  return result;
};

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(hist('aacbdgtg')) + '</pre>');
```

---

Check [reduce method polyfill option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill) for old browsers.

---

Of using simple [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) only

```js
var hist = function(str) {
  var result = [],
    temp = {},
    strArr = str.split('');

  // generate the object which holds string count
  for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    temp[strArr[i]] = temp[strArr[i]] + 1 || 1;
  }

  // generate the result using the object
  var keys = Object.keys(temp);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    result.push([keys[i], temp[keys[i]]]);
  }

  return result;
};

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(hist('aacbdgtg')) + '</pre>');
```